# Error occurs when my gas fee isn't zero. Otherwise transaction runs fine with 0 gas fee

Tags: blockchain, erc-20, metamask, gas-price, hardhat-deploy

I've created a smart contract that helps user to buy erc-20 tokens in exchange of matics.
I am getting this error whenever I do some calculations in my function, which increases gas fee.

[image]

I have 0.5836 matics in my account, and I enter value of 0.001 matics to buy erc20 token.

Here is my purchaseToken code:

```
function purchaseTokens(
     
        //AssetDetails memory assetInfo

        //address _priceFeedAddress
    ) external payable {
        // Transfer tokens from the owner (seller) to the buyer
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(priceFeedAddress);
        maticPrice = getConversionRate(msg.value, priceFeed);
      
        uint256 maticsRequiredForOneToken = 1000/maticPrice;
        //uint256 _maticsRequired = (amount*assetInfo.price);
        
        uint256 tokensPurchase = msg.value / maticsRequiredForOneToken;
        balance = msg.value;
        //require(balance > maticsNeeded, "You need more MATICS!");
      
        assetNewToken.transferFrom(owner,msg.sender, tokensPurchase);
     
        emit TokenSold(tx.origin, msg.value,  assetNewToken.getAssetDetails(300));
    }
```

Transaction runs fine if my gas fee is zero.

Here's my complete smart contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;
import "./NewToken.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
// Struct to represent asset details

contract AssetTokenSale {
    // Address of the token being sold
    address public tokenAddress;
    address public owner;
    AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeed;
    address public priceFeedAddress;
    uint256 public maticPrice;
    uint256 public balance;
    address public userAddress;
    //Ass AssetNewToken(tokenAddress)
    AssetNewToken assetNewToken;
    //MyToken contractCreateToken
    // Event to notify when tokens are sold
    event TokenSold(
        address indexed buyer,
        uint256 amount,
        AssetDetails assetInfo
    );

    // Modifier to ensure that only the owner can execute a function
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function getConversionRate(uint256 maticAmount, AggregatorV3Interface priceFeedI) internal view returns (uint256)
    {
        (, int256 answer, , , ) = priceFeedI.latestRoundData();
        //uint256 ethPrice = getPrice(priceFeed);
        uint256 maticAmountInUsd = (uint256(answer) * maticAmount) / 1000000000000000000;
        // or (Both will do the same thing)
        // uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1e18; // 1 * 10 ** 18 == 1000000000000000000
        // the actual ETH/USD conversion rate, after adjusting the extra 0s.
        return maticAmountInUsd;
    }

    // Constructor initializes the token sale
    constructor(address _tokenAddress, address _priceFeedAddress, address _userAddress) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
        userAddress = _userAddress;
        assetNewToken = AssetNewToken(_tokenAddress);
        priceFeedAddress = _priceFeedAddress;
    }

    function getPrice() public  {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(priceFeedAddress);
        maticPrice = getConversionRate(1000000000000000000, priceFeed);
    }
    function getSender() public view returns (address) {
        
         return  userAddress;
    }
    // Function to allow investors to purchase tokens
    function purchaseTokens(
     
        //AssetDetails memory assetInfo

        //address _priceFeedAddress
    ) external payable {
        // Transfer tokens from the owner (seller) to the buyer
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(priceFeedAddress);
        maticPrice = getConversionRate(msg.value, priceFeed);
      
        uint256 maticsRequiredForOneToken = 1000/maticPrice;
        //uint256 _maticsRequired = (amount*assetInfo.price);
        
        uint256 tokensPurchase = msg.value / maticsRequiredForOneToken;
        balance = msg.value;
        //require(balance > maticsNeeded, "You need more MATICS!");
      
        assetNewToken.transferFrom(owner,msg.sender, tokensPurchase);
     
        emit TokenSold(tx.origin, msg.value,  assetNewToken.getAssetDetails(300));
    }
}
```

I am doing it in hardhat and testing it on mumbai testnet. Can someone please help me in this regard. I've also added "allowUnlimitedContractSize: true" in my hardhat.config.js.

hardhat.config.js:

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();
require("hardhat-deploy");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL;
const MUMBAI_RPC_URL = process.env.MUMBAI_RPC_URL;
const Private_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const Private_KEY_USER = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_USER;
const Etherscan_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY;
const POLYGON_SCAN_API_KEY = process.env.POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY;

module.exports = {
  defaultNetworks: "hardhat",

  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [Private_KEY],
      chainId: 11155111,
      blockConfirmations: 6,
    },
    mumbai: {
      url: MUMBAI_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [Private_KEY, Private_KEY_USER],
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
      chainId: 80001,
      hardhat: {
        blockGasLimit: 100000000429720, // whatever you want here
      },
      gas: 8000000, // Set the gas limit
      gasPrice: 1000000000,
      blockConfirmations: 6,
    },
    // localhost: {
    //   url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545/",
    //   chainId: 31337,
    // },
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: {
      polygonMumbai: POLYGON_SCAN_API_KEY,
    },
  },
  solidity: {
    compilers: [{ version: "0.8.20" }, { version: "0.7.6" }],
  },
  namedAccounts: {
    //by default 0th account is deployer
    deployer: {
      default: 0,
    },
    user: {
      default: 1,
    },
  },

  settings: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 5000,
      details: { yul: false },
    },
  },
};
```